# Firebase Push Notification icon ignoring color

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:value="@color/orange" />
```

`@drawable/ic_notification` is partially white, partially transparent. `@color/orange` is set in `values/colors.xml` as `#F25826`.

Yet the push notification icon is always shown in white, ignoring the `@color/orange` set. Why is that?

I am not using `NotificationCompat`, I simply followed the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). I tried using `mipmap` instead of `drawable`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `00F25826` instead of `F25826` - while this is only the default, unless set otherwise.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That doesn't compile, `Invalid <color> for given resource value.`.